# Function Keeps Looping After Last Row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I am using the following code to fill a Google Docs template with data pulled from a spreadsheet.

```
function createBulkMembershipCards() {

const template = DriveApp.getFileById("--------");
const docFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("----------");
const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("----------------");
const libroSoci = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("LibroSoci");

const data = libroSoci.getRange(352, 1, libroSoci.getLastRow()-1,19).getDisplayValues();

data.forEach(row => {
  
  createMembershipCard (row[3],row[4],row[0],row[1], row[6],template,docFolder,pdfFolder);
  
});

}

function createMembershipCard (name,surname,msnumber,timestamp, email,template,docFolder,pdfFolder) {

const file = template.makeCopy(docFolder);
const docFile = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
const body = docFile.getBody();

body.replaceText("{name}", name);
body.replaceText("{surname}", surname);
body.replaceText("{msnumber}", msnumber);
body.replaceText("{timestamp}", timestamp);
body.replaceText("{email}", "<<"+email+">>");
docFile.saveAndClose();

docFile.setName(msnumber+" "+name+" "+surname);

const pdfBlob = docFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
pdfFolder.createFile(pdfBlob).setName(msnumber+" "+name+" "+surname);

}
```

I do not understand why, even though I used "getLastRow", the function keeps going on indefinitely after the last populated row.

Please not that I put 352 as the starting row because I want to extract data from that row on.

Is anyone able to help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say getLastRow() returns 1000.  Then you are getting 999 rows.  What you want is 1000-351 rows.

Change

```
const data = libroSoci.getRange(352, 1, libroSoci.getLastRow()-1,19).getDisplayValues();
```

To

```
const data = libroSoci.getRange(352, 1, libroSoci.getLastRow()-351,19).getDisplayValues();
```